# Chrome: is there an event for user disconnected headphones?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm writing a music-streaming web app (desktop use, if it matter), and I want to be able to auto-pause the player when the user disconnected their headphones.

Is this at all possible to do via Chrome (or any other browser for that matter)?

Ideally what I would want is:

```
headphones.onDisconnect(function() {
    player.pause();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Since this is a desktop app, I would recommend searching to see if there are native OS APIs for that. I do not think anything like that exists in chrome.

Comment: Back then, it would have been possible to do it by intercepting the event with an NPAPI plugin. However, some people have filled the internet with malwares and Google started blocking a bunch of features to protect their users against that. I'd say it's not possible directly from Chrome, but you could use a desktop application and send your jack events through a WebSocket and listen to it from Chrome as well.

Comment: You may be able to check if there is an Audio card enabled on the computer by checking either `new AudioContext().destination.channelCount` or `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices` but for headphones... I think you're out of luck, and mostly if you want to do it in a cross-platform way. Just add a pause button easily accessible.

Comment: It might not be possible with chrome, but in the context of a desktop app using something like, electron or nw.js, you can get more control of the underlying OS.

Comment: This will be possible in the future have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/API/AudioChannelManager/headphones